# Python XML parsing - multisections

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML file like following:

```
<item>
  <global>

    <option id="123b25-1323-2f">
      <name>Bla</name>
      <number>0123987</number>
    </option>
    <option id="aeb12f-91b3-57">
      <name>Foo</name>
      <number>92309</number>
    </option>

    <section id="aeee72-0965-66">
      <name>alb</name>
      <number>0123987</number>
    </section>
    <section id="928374-11b3-51">
      <name>oof</name>
      <number>92309</number>
    </section>

  </global>
</item>
```

What is the best way to build a dictionary fo e.g. option and section with python2.7 and an appropriate module.
Example Code:

```
root = XMLTree(xml) # xml ist file or string
global = root.getSubsection('global')
options = global.getItems('option')
sections = global.getItems('section')

print options
```

I wish Output like this:

```
=> {'id-123b25-1323-2f': {'name': 'Bla', 'number': '0123987'}, 'id-aeb12f-91b3-57': {'name': 'Foo', 'number': '92309'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is a very appropriate standard library module. Here is a suggestion (Python 2.7):

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def get_items(elements):
    D = {elem.get("id"): dict((child.tag, child.text) for child in elem) 
         for elem in elements}
    return D

tree = ET.parse("item.xml")
options = tree.findall(".//option")
sections = tree.findall(".//section")

print "options:"
print get_items(options)
print "sections:"
print get_items(sections)
```

Output:

```
options:
{'aeb12f-91b3-57': {'name': 'Foo', 'number': '92309'}, '123b25-1323-2f': {'name': 'Bla', 'number': '0123987'}}
sections:
{'928374-11b3-51': {'name': 'oof', 'number': '92309'}, 'aeee72-0965-66': {'name': 'alb', 'number': '0123987'}}
```

Comment: that looks exactly like what im looking for. i cannot try it at the moment, but thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had come across this module and it was quite useful. 
[XML to Dict](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use xml.dom.minidom to parse the xml string and extract the elements to create a dictionary. Here is an example with minidom

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom = parseString(data) #xml dom object from xml
def getItems(node): 
    """dom parser and xml generator"""
    return {node.getAttribute('id'): 
                 dict((e.nodeName, e.firstChild.data) 
                      for e in node.childNodes if e.nodeType == dom.ELEMENT_NODE)
            for node in node }

options = dom.getElementsByTagName('option')
sections = dom.getElementsByTagName('section')
getItems(options)
{u'aeb12f-91b3-57': {u'name': u'Foo', u'number': u'92309'}, u'123b25-1323-2f': {u'name': u'Bla', u'number': u'0123987'}}
getItems(sections)
{u'928374-11b3-51': {u'name': u'oof', u'number': u'92309'}, u'aeee72-0965-66': {u'name': u'alb', u'number': u'0123987'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import lxml.etree as et

doc=et.fromstring(xml)

def getItems(doc,name):
    d={}
    for elem in doc.xpath('.//{0}'.format(name)):
        attr=elem.xpath('.//@id')[0]
        items=[(i.tag, i.text) for i in elem.xpath('.//*')]
        d[attr]={k:v for k,v in items}  
    return d
print getItems(doc,'option')
print getItems(doc,'section')
```

Output:

```
{'aeb12f-91b3-57': {'name': 'Foo', 'number': '92309'}, '123b25-1323-2f': {'name': 'Bla', 'number': '0123987'}}
{'928374-11b3-51': {'name': 'oof', 'number': '92309'}, 'aeee72-0965-66': {'name': 'alb', 'number': '0123987'}}
```